# SpringBoot reads all properties as 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Using SpringBoot, I'm having simple class

```
@Component
@PropertySource("server.properties")
public class CoreFacade {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CoreFacade.class);

    @Value("${chat.server.port}")
    private int port;
    private Server server;

    public CoreFacade() {
        log.info(String.valueOf(port));
        server = new Server(port);
    }
}
```

and under src/main/resources I got server.properties with 
`chat.server.port = 9999`

Yet logging this ends up with

> INFO    2018-08-20 21:48:02,878 [main]
>   com.example.chatserver.core.CoreFacade [] [] - 0

instead of 9999

Any ideas what could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Ofcourse it will. You are logging it in the constructor, the `@Value` will be resolved afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You annotated your class as a Spring component.
It prints `0` as the constructor is invoked by Spring before any dependency injection done for the bean.
What you need is to declaring the class as a configuration class such as :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("server.properties")
public class CoreFacade {
 ...
}
```

If it makes sense you could make `Server` a bean defined in the class such as  :

```
@Value("${chat.server.port}")
private int port;

@Bean
public Server server() {
     return new Server(port); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, `@Configuration` alone wasn't enough, I had to use `@Bean` as well. But correct me if I'm wrong, everytime Ill use `getServer()` I'll get new instance of `Server` this way? If I dont want that, the only way is to do `@Bean public Server server() { this.server = new Server(port); return null; }` ?

Comment: never methods annotated with `@Bean`  create a single time the bean whatever the number of time you invoke the method. But if you specified the prototype scope.  `@Bean` should not be required on the class.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution as the one proposed by davidxxx, is to mark your constructor as @Autowired :

```
@Component
@PropertySource("server.properties")
public class CoreFacade {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CoreFacade.class);

    private Server server;

    @Autowired
    public CoreFacade(
        @Value("${chat.server.port}")
        int port
    ) {
        log.info(String.valueOf(port));
        server = new Server(port);
    }
}
```

You could also use @PostConstruct, which is called after @Value resolution :

```
@Component
@PropertySource("server.properties")
public class CoreFacade {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CoreFacade.class);

    @Value("${chat.server.port}")
    private int port;
    private Server server;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        log.info(String.valueOf(port));
        server = new Server(port);
    }
}
```